# Google+ API redirect uri

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-plus

I want get OAuth from Google+. I'm doing

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=952790678356&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me&response_type=token"]]];
```

I know that problem in the redirect URI, but I haven't got the redirect uri, it's `http:// localhost`. I try with redirect URI `http:// localhost` and it doesn't work. Maybe somebody know what I must write in redirect URI?

Comment: Right now you're using the no-redirect method of completing OAuth by specifying redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob. Are you sure that you really want the redirect URL to be localhost? On an iPhone that would indicate that you're running a local web server.

Comment: I only need to get OAuth, but if I not write redirect uri - I have error

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ iOS SDK and sample application demonstrates how you can use the installed application OAuth flow (with the Sign in with Google+ button). With this SDK, you will be able to register your **Bundle ID** instead.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/